# mvc getting and sending data from dropdown and datetimepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetimepicker, html.dropdownlistfor

hello everyone I have a question. I have a form which consist of dropdown textbox and datetimepicker. I can fill my dropdown from my model but I cannot post the data to the database. Here are my codes

My Controller codes this is where the data selected and shown in view

```
public ActionResult orderProduct()
    {
        Repository<OrderProduct> _ro = new Repository<OrderProduct>();
        IEnumerable<OrderProduct> _orderProduct = _ro.All().OrderByDescending(o => o.id);

        return View(_orderProduct);
    }
```

I am filling the dropdownlist from database

```
public ActionResult addOrderProduct()
    {
        /*
        Repository<Workshop> _rw = new Repository<Workshop>();
        IEnumerable<Workshop> _workshop = _rw.All().OrderByDescending(o => o.id);



        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _selectList = from w in _workshop
                                                  select new SelectListItem {
                                                      Text = w.name,
                                                      Value = w.id.ToString()
                                                  };
        */

        Repository<Workshop> _rw = new Repository<Workshop>();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _workshopSelectListItem = _rw.All().AsEnumerable().Select(s => 
            new SelectListItem { 
                Text = s.name, Value=s.id.ToString()
            });


        ViewData["dropdown"] = _workshopSelectListItem;

        return View();
    }
```

here I am trying to post my data to the database. I cannot select data from dropdown and datetimepicker also I cannot post this data by writing manually.

```
public ActionResult orderProductAdd(int adet, float cmt)
    {
        Repository<OrderProduct> _rp = new Repository<OrderProduct>();
        OrderProduct _orderProduct = new OrderProduct { workshopId = 1, orderId = 1, value = adet, shipDate = new DateTime(2005, 02, 01), cmt = cmt };

        return RedirectToAction("orderProduct");
    }
```

this is my model

```
 [Table("OrderProduct")]
public class OrderProduct
{


    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }


    public int orderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("orderId")]
    public virtual Order order { get; set; }

    public int workshopId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("workshopId")]
    public virtual Workshop workshop { get; set; }

    public int value { get; set; }
    public float cmt { get; set; }

    public DateTime shipDate { get; set; }

    /*
     [id]
  ,[orderId]
  ,[workshopId]
  ,[value]
  ,[cmt]
  ,[shipDate]
     */
}
```

and also this is my view "addOrderProduct"

```
   <form action="/Order/orderProductAdd" class="form-horizontal">


    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Atölye Seçiniz</label>
        <div class="controls">
           @Html.DropDownList("dropdown",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["dropdown"],"secim yapınız", new { @class = "span6 chosen" })
            @*<select class="span6 chosen" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Category 1">A1</option>
                <option value="Category 2">A2</option>
                <option value="Category 3">A3</option>
                <option value="Category 4">A4</option>
            </select>*@
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Adet Giriniz</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span6 " name="adet" />
            <span class="help-inline">Sadece sayı giriniz</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group last">
        <label class="control-label">İhracat Tarihi</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div id="ui_date_picker_inline"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Cmt</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="span6 " name="cmt" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Onayla</button>
        @*<button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>*@
    </div>


</form>
```

How can I solve this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument in the DDL (below) is the assigned parameter being passed back to the server. When you call the action you're not passing the parameter `dropdown`. You're only calling `int adet, float cmt` but not a parameter called `dropdown`

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["dropdown"],
"secim yapınız", new { @class = "span6 chosen" })
```

So update your code to something like the one below:

```
public ActionResult orderProductAdd(int adet, float cmt, string dropdown){
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
}
```

I can't see the input control which is being constructed for the DATETIME part of your query, however it will be similar to the above. Ensure the name of the INPUT matches the parameters being passed back to the server.

Comment: thank you for the answer but I have also another inputs such as "adet"  and "cmt" and in orderProductAdd how can I reach the dropdown's selected id and value.

Comment: Just add `string dropdown` along side `adet` and `cmt` in the form action. I'll update the answer to show you. Also note, you named the DDL in the view as `dropdown`, this is why I am saying you need to add a parameter called `dropdown` to your code.

Comment: It's already been updated, take another look at the ActionResult I posted

Comment: oh ok sorry but I have already done this but what is next what should I do inside the parenthesis how can I reach this dropdown id and value

Comment: Put a breakpoint within your code, is it passing a value into `dropdown` on the server logic when you submit the form? If it is, just do what you need within the code and when you require the value from `dropdown` just call it from the parameter you passed into the Action. If no value is being passed into the Action for the DDL then let me know.